# How to Upgrade from Discontinued Skype for Linux 4.3

Tags: 14.04, skype

Skype was working perfectly on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS until some time early November 2017. When I launch skype from the terminal, the login box pops up, I enter my credentials and then skype just closes. The terminal has a lot of output, ending in

`Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`

Can I reinstall Skype?

Comment: which version of skype do you have? yes you can reinstall it

Comment: @dobey the post you suggest is now outdated since legacy Skype for Linux application (v4.*) is now discontinued. The solution below works since Nov 2017. I welcome feedback on how to make this clearer (I have changed the title, for instance), but felt the community would benefit from a clear answer on how to deal with the Nov 2017 update.

Comment: @user304497 The highest voted answer, and one that appears first on the page, exactly describes getting the new skypeforlinux from the Skype web site. There is nothing special about November, beyond Skype disabling 4.3 entirely. The skypeforlinux package has been available for a long while now, with legacy skype not receiving any support, and announced it would eventually be disabled entirely (which it now is).

Comment: @dobey Apologies, you are correct. I didn't read the top solution carefully enough. This is indeed a duplicate and this page should be removed. I don't think I am able to do this myself, so if a moderator could remove the question I'd be grateful.

Comment: I have flagged the question for deletion

Answer (score 0):

It appears Skype has been upgraded (see [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_linux-skype_startms-skype_installms/end-of-life-of-skype-for-linux-43/70fe7036-ddf3-4fa3-9c06-1bca3ec0226c)). First remove your old skype

`$ sudo apt-get --purge remove skype:i386
$ rm -r ~/.Skype/`

Then go here https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/ and choose 'Get Skype for Linux DEB'.

Once the `.deb` file has been downloaded, right-click on the `.deb` file, and open with Ubuntu Software Centre. If this isn't listed, click on 'Open with Other Application' > 'Show Other Applications' > 'Ubuntu Software Centre'. Once loaded into Ubuntu Software Centre, click the 'install' button.

Once the installation is complete, either launch from the terminal with

`$ skypeforlinux`

or click on the top left icon on the launcher on the Ubuntu desktop. Type in 'skype', and click on the Skype icon under 'Applications'. This will launch your newly installed skype.